# Template class copy constructor

Tags: c++, templates, copy-constructor

I want to write copy constructor for a template class. I have this class:

```
template<int C>
class Word {
    array<int, C> bitCells; //init with zeros
    int size;

public:
    //constructor fill with zeros
    Word<C>() {
        //bitCells = new array<int,C>;
        for (int i = 0; i < C; i++) {
            bitCells[i] = 0;
        }
        size = C;
    }
    Word<C>(const Word<C>& copyObg) {
        size=copyObg.getSize();
        bitCells=copyObg.bitCells;
    }
}
```

I have errors with the copy constructor, on the line of intilizeing the size, I get:
"Multiple markers at this line
    - passing 'const Word<16>' as 'this' argument of 'int Word::getSize() [with int C = 16]' discards qualifiers [-
     fpermissive]
    - Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: int getSize() '"

what is wrong with this ?
thank you

Comment: First step: remove `<C>` after the constructor names.

Comment: Based on the error, the member `getSize()` your code excerpt doesn't include is a non-`const` member: make it a `const` member.

Comment: like this: "Word(const Word<C>& copyObg)" ? why is that?
(still same error..)

Comment: It seems like you don't need to define a copy constructor yourself; the implicitly defined one should do just fine.

Comment: The name of the constructor is `Word`, not `Word<C>`. You would use `Word<C>` for the class name in an out of line definition of the constructor: `template <int C> Word<C>::Word(Word<C> const& copyObg) { ... }`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: yes - if we wanted to turn this code into real code rather than helping along with the problem it would look rather different, e.g., the default ctor would look like `Word(): bitCells(), size(C) {}`

Answer (score 3):

I'd write the class like this:

```
template <std::size_t N>
class Word
{
    std::array<int, N> bit_cells_;

public:
    static constexpr std::size_t size = N;

    Word() : bit_cells_{} {}

    // public functions
};
```

Note:

- No need for a dynamic size, since it's part of the type.
- No need for special member functions, since the implicitly defined ones are fine.
- Initialize the member array to zero via the constructor-initializer-list.
- Template parameter is unsigned, since it represents a count.

Comment: Regarding your last point: This has the negative consequence of breaking something like `static_assert(N >= 0, "Array size must be positive");`, which could become dangerous if the template parameter of `Word` is not a negative integer literal but a negative result of some compile-time calculation (`Word<A::size - B::size>`). It's basically the same problem as with unsigned function parameters.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong is that your `getSize()` is not declared `const`.  Make it so:

```
int getSize() const { return size; }
```